# Flutter Data in Firestore gets displayed in the ui after it is saved to firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, save, load

I have a List with Songs, after adding a Song to the List it gets saved to Firestore. Every time I add a new Song to the List and Save it to Firestore, the complete list in the Database is added to the List in the UI again. At first, i thought my Loadall list that gets called at the beginning is getting triggered somehow but after some testing, the saveSong Method is causing this problem.
Here is my Code

These are my buttons to add a song and to load the list from firebase

I will not include the build widgets because that's not important.

```
 FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
          onPressed: () {
            checkSong(Song(
                title: textfieldControllersong.text, like: false, likes: 0));
            reloadlist();
            textfieldControllersong.clear();
            /*addSong(Song(
                title: textfieldControllersong.text, like: false, likes: 0));*/
          },
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          _loadAll();
        })
```

I have two addSongs methods. One is called from the loadall method to add these to my list and the other is from the user input

```
void addSong(Song item) {
    setState(() {
      list.add(item);
    });
    _saveSong(item);
  }

  void addSongfire(Song item) {
    setState(() {
      list.add(item);
    });
  }
void checkSong(Song item) {
    bool isSongFound = false;
    list.forEach((s) {
      if (s.title.trim() == item.title.trim()) {
        setState(() {
          s.likes++;
        });
        isSongFound = true;
      }
    });
    if (!isSongFound) {
      addSong(Song(title: textfieldControllersong.text, like: false, likes: 0));
      /*_saveSong(
          Song(title: textfieldControllersong.text, like: false, likes: 0));*/
    }
  }
```

These are the Methods to save and Load the Songs I guess that the error comes from saveSong but I don't know why after saveSong is triggered every data from Firesore gets added to the List in the UI again.

```
void _saveSong(Song item) async {
    CollectionReference fire = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Songs');
    await fire
        .add({"title": item.title, "like": item.like, "likes": item.likes});
  }

  void _loadAll() {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Songs')
        .orderBy("likes")
        .snapshots();
    stream.forEach((QuerySnapshot snap) {
      print("here");
      snap.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        addSongFirestore(
            doc.data()['title'], doc.data()['likes'], doc.data()['like']);
      });
    });
  }

void addSongFirestore(String titlef, int likesf, bool likef) {
    addSongfire(Song(title: titlef, like: likef, likes: likesf));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting your data once when you call `_getAll` you are attaching a listener to that node. A listener will give you the whole node when you attach it but will also call your `addSongfire` when data changes on that node.

To fix your isseu you could initialize the listener in your Widget `initState` override or you just change your `_getAll` to only get the data once like this:

```dart
Future _loadAll() async {
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Songs')
      .orderBy("likes")
      .get();

  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      addSongFirestore(
          doc.data()['title'], doc.data()['likes'], doc.data()['like']);
    }
  });
}
```

This will add the data only once and only when you call it with your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Answer! It works like a charm now haha. So the Loadall Method was causing the error, good to know!